# Wrap a few lines of Algorithmic in a box

Tags: boxes, algorithmic, adjustbox

I have some pseudocode where I want to reveal an algorithm little-by-little. Currently I highlight the code that is revealed by coloring it red and this looks good onscreen. However, on print, this coloring is difficult to see so I additionally want to highlight the lines that are revealed by wrapping them inside a box. *I want this to also include the line numbers*. How can I do this?

I've provided a picture of what I want to achieve below, and added the MWE at the bottom (btw, is there a simple way of copying and pasting code snippets onto this page? I had to manually adjust the indentation of the code in order for it to be recognized as such, which was very annoying).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{adjustbox}{tabular={ll},center}

    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{lightgray!20}
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}     
    &
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{red}
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \color{lightgray!20}
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf      
        \end{algorithmic}       
    \end{adjustbox}
    \\
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \color{red}
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf      
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}

\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very unelegant solution, but it works. Note that you have to compile *twice*.

[image: Result]

1. Using `tikz` define a macro `\tikzmark` which uses a "invisible" picture with `remember picture` and `overlay` options. This allows you to give a name to the coordinates of that point, which can be used later to draw things on top of the page. There is a package named [tikzmark](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark), which has a much more versatile and robust implementation, but for this particular case the "simple" version is enough.
2. Just before each listing, put `\tikzmark{left}` to give a name to the coordinate of the top left corner of that listing. This will be used as reference for the left border of the box.
3. Put `\tikzmark{begin}` before the first red line. This will be used as reference for the top border of the box.
4. Put `\tikzmark{end}` after the last red line. This will be used as reference for the bottom border of the box.
5. Use a tikzpicture with `remember picture` and `overlay` options, and use the before named coordinates and some calc to draw the red box as desired.

The following code implements this idea. For easier repetition, the code which draws the red box was extracted to a macro. You simply have to put `\drawredbox` after the listing which defined `(left)`, `(begin)` and `(end)` coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node [anchor=base] (#1) {};}%

\def\drawredbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[thick, red] ($(left|-begin)+(2pt,-2pt)$) rectangle ($(left|-end)+(4cm,-2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}



\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{adjustbox}{tabular={ll},center}

    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{lightgray!20}
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}     
    &
    \tikzmark{left}% <-------------------------------------- left
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{red}\tikzmark{begin} % <------------------ begin
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \color{lightgray!20}\tikzmark{end} % <----------- end
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}\drawredbox % <-------- Drawing of the red box
    \\
    \tikzmark{left}% <-------------------------------------- left
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \color{red}\tikzmark{begin}% <------------------ begin
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf\tikzmark{end} % <------------------------ end      
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}\drawredbox % <------- Drawing of the red box
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

You can tweak the fixed dimensions used for the width of the red box and the distance to the baselines.

Comment: This worked. The only thing I noticed was that the first code panel, which did not have a red box written over it, would lose its alignment with the other panels (it's shifted a bit to the left). I solved this by adding a box to it too, having 0 width and 0 height. However, I don't whether this is how it should be?

Comment: @hakoja I don't see that shift in my example image... Perhaps it is due to some "invisible" space in the source code, such as a newline at the end of a environment, which TeX translates into a space. Note that ending a line with a `%` the newline is "commented out", and then that space will not appear.

Comment: I noticed now that I don't actually have to draw the red box, BUT I do need to add a `\tikzmark{left}` just before the first `\begin{adjustbox}...` of the first panel. Without that the misalignment appears. Strange...With regards to withe space I've tried to add `%`'s wherever I can, but I don't really know where they should be placed :-D

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have a solution with tikz. This one works also with `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` and can be easily nodified to change the marked lines with the placement of two marker nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\scriptsize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{adjustbox}{tabular={ll},center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\node at(0,0){\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{lightgray!20}
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}};\end{tikzpicture} 
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}\node (tmp) at (0,0){\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \color{red}
            \tikz{\node(tmp1){};}\ElsIf{code}%Mark line to start the rectangle
                \State code \tikz{\node(tmp2){};}%Mark line to finish the rectangle
            \color{lightgray!20}
            \Else
                \State code
            \EndIf      
        \end{algorithmic}      
    \end{adjustbox}};
    \path(tmp1-|tmp.west) -- +(2ex,-0.5em)node(tmp3){};%Place the first corner of the rectangle
    \path(tmp2-|tmp.east) -- +(-2ex,-0.5em)node(tmp4){};%Place the second corner of the rectangle
    \draw[red](tmp3) rectangle (tmp4);\end{tikzpicture}%draw the rectangle
    \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}\node (tmp) at (0,0){\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][]{.62\linewidth},fbox}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
            \Statex         
            \If{code}
                \State code
            \ElsIf{code}
                \State code 
            \color{red}
            \tikz{\node(tmp1){};}\Else%Mark line to start the rectangle
                \State code\tikz{\node(tmp2){};} %Mark line to start the rectangle
            \EndIf  
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{adjustbox}};
    \path(tmp1-|tmp.west) -- +(2ex,-0.5em)node(tmp3){};%Place the first corner of the rectangle
    \path(tmp2-|tmp.east) -- +(-2ex,-0.5em)node(tmp4){};%Place the second corner of the rectangle
    \draw[red](tmp3) rectangle (tmp4);\end{tikzpicture}%draw the rectangle
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

The nodes `tmp1` and `tmp2` are used in this case to mark the lines that should be highlighted. The negative y-shift of the nodes by 0.5em is needed because the nodes `tmp1` and `tmp2` are actually added in the line above. Changing the width of the colored rectangle is easily done with the placement of `tmp4`.

Produced Output:
[image]
Produced Output with `\path(tmp2-|tmp) -- +(0em,-0.5em)node(tmp4){};`:
[image]